# Processor Design- Hazard management unit

Tags: processor, pipeline, instruction-set, no-op

I am designing a cell SPE processor. I have to check for data hazards before I take data from register file. What is the best way to identify the number of stall cycles necessary and what design decisions should I take about where to stall the pipeline? I am looking for a general view on the subject.

Comment: do you design a verilog of newer version of SPE or do you just programming an existing SPE?

Comment: designing a newer version of SPE. Lesser instructions but taken from all types. But same pipeline.

Comment: try to look here http://books.google.com/books?id=TkBC2q90NM8C and here http://books.google.com/books?id=-1kX4CV-IdQC&pg=PA909 and http://books.google.com/books?id=JEYKyfZ3yF0C&pg=PA22&dq=stall+pipeline+cpu

Comment: Thank you. I have finished the project. But I'll take a look anyway.